# "Coin change 2": Why is this dynamic programming implementation not efficient enough?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, memoization

I am working on a [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/) problem, [518. Coin Change II](https://leetcode.com/problems/coin-change-ii/description/):

> You are given an integer array `coins` representing coins of different denominations and an integer `amount` representing a total amount of money.
>
> Return *the number of combinations that make up that amount*. If that amount of money cannot be made up by any combination of the coins, return `0`.
>
> You may assume that you have an infinite number of each kind of coin.

Here is the code I tried with:

```
class Solution {
    public int func(int[] arr,int sum,int i,int[][] dp){
        if(i>=arr.length) return 0;
        if(sum==0) return 1;
        if(sum<0) return 0;
        if(dp[i][sum]!=-1) return dp[i][sum];
        else{
            int t=func(arr,sum-arr[i],i,dp);
            int nt=func(arr,sum,i+1,dp);
            return t+nt;
        }
    }

    public int change(int amount, int[] coins) {
        int[][] dp=new int[coins.length][amount+1];
        for(int[] arr:dp){
            Arrays.fill(arr,-1);
        }
        return func(coins,amount,0,dp);
    }
}
```

But it fails with a "Time Limit Exceeded" error for the following input:

```
amount = 500
coins = [3,5,7,8,9,10,11]
```

I have another implementation that does not run into this time-out:

```
class Solution {
    public int func(int[] arr,int sum,int start,int[][] dp){
        if(sum==0) return 1;
        if(sum<0) return 0;
        if(dp[start][sum]!=-1) return dp[start][sum];
        else{
            int s=0;
            for(int i=start;i<arr.length;i++){
                s+=func(arr,sum-arr[i],i,dp);
            }
            return dp[start][sum]= s;
        }
    }

    public int change(int amount, int[] coins) {
        int[][] dp=new int[coins.length][amount+1];
        for(int[] arr:dp){
            Arrays.fill(arr,-1);
        }
        return func(coins,amount,0,dp);
    }
}
```

There are some minor differences in the approach, but I can't see a major difference. What is the difference that explains why my implementation is not efficient enough?

Comment: one points (after a fast overview): first is eventually doing `return dp[i][sum]` but never changing the initial value of the elements of `dp` (missing the inner loop is also a bit suspicious)

Answer (score 1):

The first version has not written found results into `dp`, so it cannot take benefit from memoization. As the tests will include up to 500 different coins and amounts up to 5000, the number of times the function is called with the same arguments will be enormous.

To activate the memoization, change the `return` statement to:

```
return dp[i][sum]=t+nt;
```

...similarly to what the second version does.